# Google Maps API JavaScript and ZK

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zk

I am work in ZK and now I am need use the Google API maps. I have used this API in other framework sometimes.
I don't  show the maps. 
Firstly I thought the problem may be the css, but it isn't.
I added a initialize (maps) function to a event onLoad of windows but I had still the same problem. I debug the code in the browser with the js console and I seen that the window event load isn't available so I called the function initialize from the event load from the div (which contents the maps), again the js console showed the same message.
I use a directive

```
 <div  id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;" xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client" w:onClick="initialize()"></div>
```

But the div wasn't shown.
Finally I used a pure html element, using the html tag of ZK:

```
<html><![CDATA[
    <div id="map_canvas" onload="initialize()" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"/>
 ]]></html>
```

but the result in the js console is again

```
<div class="noscript"><p>Sorry, JavaScript must be enabled.<br/>Change your browser options, then <a href="">try again</a>.</p></div>
```

I'd like know way the function which shows the maps don't do it. I think the problem is the js but I am not sure, do anybody tell me if the problem is the js called please?

Thanks.

Edit:

I have used this way to do it (Thank you very much to Sean Connolly: [How get the zk element id from js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231893/how-get-the-zk-element-id-from-js))

```
<zk>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&amp;sensor=false">
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    var map;
    function initialize() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(zk.Widget.$(jq('$map_canvas2')).$n(), mapOptions);
    }      
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map_canvas2" style="width: 1320px; height: 1480px;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address},
    function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

           alert(results[0].geometry.location.latlng[0]);



        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
initialize();
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;" onClick="initialize()"></div>
```