# How get the zk element id from js

Tags: javascript, zk

I am working with ZK and I want to get the id of the a zk element from js.
I have used differents ways:

Declaring the component like native html and it gets the id from js but it isn't correct.
I have declared the element using the html tags of ZK but isn't correct too.
I have seen some functions like Component.getFellow('component_name') and finally I have read about the UUID and use some example codes but I can't the element id for example:

```
<label id=titleBook/>
```

from javaScript.

any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that **the `id` you assign an element in ZUL (ZK markup) is not one-to-one with the rendered DOM element id**. ZK does this for a number of reasons, but the take away is that you need to reference the DOM elements without knowing their id.

ZK makes this easy by giving you a JavaScript framework also, they refer to it as 'Client Side Programming' a lot.

Have a look at ZK's documentation on Client Side Programming, specifically the paragraph on ["How to Get Widget Reference in JavaScript"](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Client_Side_Programming#How_to_Get_Widget_Reference_in_JavaScript).

Here you'll see that the [ZK JavaScript APIs](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/) provide

```
<zk xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client">
    <label id="titleBook"/>
    <button label="button"
            w:onClick="this.$f('titleBook').setValue('sean is cool')" />
</zk>
```

Note that I am defining the `w` namespace to be ZK's client library just to fire the client side `onClick` event where I have access to `this`, the [Button widget](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/zul/wgt/Button.html).

It sounds like you are probably working in vanilla JS would do something more like..

```
<zk>
    <script defer="true">
        jq("$titleBook").css('color', 'green');
        zk("$titleBook").setValue('sean is cool');
    </script>
    <label id="titleBook"/>
</zk>
```

Here we're leveraging the [`jq()`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/_global_/jq.html) and [`zk()`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/_global_/jq.html#zk) globals in the ZK JavaScript APIs. The former is just jQuery's `$()` and the latter is the ZK counterpart. The difference is that the jQuery function returns a jQuery object while the latter returns a ZK widget. Both are extended to support the new `$` CSS style selector which references the ZK widget id (what you assigned in ZUL/Java).

Comment: "while the latter returns a ZK widget." - it returns a jqzq (http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/_global_/jqzk.html) object on which you'd have to call $() to get the widget, e.g. zk("$myButtonId").$(), at least in the latest ZK version (7.0.3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
zk.Widget.$(jq('$titleBook'))
```

Comment: Test un console navegator